# How to recover objects from a database?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a database in the Assets folder of the project and I would try to recover the file of the database, but I get an exception. Can not find the file. What should I change?

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection mussAll = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("ms-appx:///../Assets/Database1.db", true);
```

Later I would like to fill a List with objects within the database. is correct to do so?

```
var queryAll = await mussAll.Table<Musei>().ToListAsync();
            List<Musei> listAll = new List<Musei>();
            foreach(Musei museiAll in queryAll)
            {
                listAll.Add(museiAll);
            }
            var qruppim = listAll.OrderBy(x => x.NomeMuseo).GroupBy(x => x.NomeMuseo.Substring(0, 1));
            MuseoDettagli.Source = qruppim;
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: `Message = "Could not open database file: C:\\Data\\Users\\DefApps\\APPDATA\\Local\\Packages\\16224StefanoDEV.OpenMUSEI_ytmhawmee91mc\\LocalState\\ms-appx:///../Assets/Database1.db (CannotOpen)" `